# Ubuntu 23 install: no operating systems detected

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have an old samsung notebook with win 10 and a partition with Kubuntu 18.04 beaver. Now I need to upgrade it to more recent version, but internal update fails since this is an unsupported version.
So I flashed a usb stick with a 23 ISO image and boot from this.
But installer does not recognize disk partitions.
I have searched and tried almost everything I've found on the web, disabled fastboot, chkdsk etc.., but with no success..
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 23 ISO, as the *snap* only products like Ubuntu Core 22 are released only on *even* years; do you mean Ubuntu 23.04? (2023-April release) or 23.10? (2023-October release). You've also not said which product, as three installers are available for 23.04 & 23.10; selected at download time (2 for Desktop & 1 for Server).

Comment: I've solved! But first I'll try to answer your question: I was trying this product:
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=23.10.1&architecture=amd64 
It is not an ISO image but an installer my fault!
Now I tried with 22.04 installer but the thing that solved my issue is this:
I've flashed the usb stick from windows with Rufus, while the first attempt I did it from the ubuntu os with another tool.
This "rufus" stick, after boot from, was able to recognize my partitions, and I was able to upgrade my 18.04 to 22. I wrote this for other people that may have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by using the Rufus app in a Windows environment to make a bootable USB Ubuntu installation thumb drive as recommended by the official Ubuntu website.